# Gdal will not import after several installs (Mac OSX)

Tags: python, macos, import, macports, gdal

Using Macports,

I've tried to install: gdal, py27gdal, and gdal-grass.  All so I can import gdal into python 2.7.2.

Neither have been successful.

When I type:

```
port list installed
```

I see the installed modules:

```
gdal-grass                     @1.4.3          gis/gdal-grass   
gdbm                           @1.8.3          databases/gdbm    
py27-gdal                      @1.7.1          python/py27-gdal
```

And when I run python to import the module:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named gdal
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the MacPorts python2.7?  Try launching Python this way:

```
/opt/local/bin/python2.7
```

Comment: Yes, that worked!  Am I able to remove all the other python versions and launch this python by "python" alone?

Comment: Don't try to remove the Apple-supplied system Pythons, they are part of OS X.  The easiest thing to do is, first, modify your shell profile to ensure MacPorts-installed ports are found (see https://trac.macports.org/wiki/InstallingMacPorts#a3.Settheshellenvironment) and then use `sudo port select python python27` to select the default python path associated with the MacPorts `python` command.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this solves your problem, but `gdal` is in the `osgeo` namespace. So you should try importing `gdal` like this:

```
from osgeo import gdal
```

The `gdal` namespace itself is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, but it's the same problem:  ImportError: No module named osgeo