# Graphics folder modules will not import after several installs (Mac OSX)

Tags: python, png, tiff

A similar problem with the python gdal module [Gdal will not import after several installs (Mac OSX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094749/gdal-will-not-import-after-several-installs-mac-osx) was solved by modifying my shell profile to ensure MacPorts-installed ports are found, and then using `sudo port select python python27`.

But this time it's every module in my graphics folder that deals with tiff and png reading and writing that will not import:

tiff                           @3.9.5          graphics/tiff

pngpp                          @0.2.3          graphics/pngpp

libgeotiff                     @1.3.0          graphics/libgeotiff

Again, when I run python to import either module I get the similar response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named png
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you create the `graphics` folder yourself?

Comment: why cant you use PIL or another imaging repository?

Comment: @Constantinius I didn't create the folder.  It was created by macports when I installed the modules.

Comment: @Jim PIL only handles reading of png, but not geotiff.  I am using satellite imagery and want to maintain the geospatial tags when I read and write to files.  Thanks guys.

Comment: So, if gdal is working, why cant't you use that one for image manipulation?

Comment: @Constanitinius gdal is working but it only has an open (read only) utility; no ability to write Tiffs/GeoTiffs.  Am I wrong?

Comment: @Constanitinius, the only file I/O that I can find in gdal: Help on built-in function Open in module _gdal:

Open(...)
    Open(char name, GDALAccess eAccess = GA_ReadOnly) -> Dataset
(END)

Comment: You posted this exact question yesterday. Don't re-post a question just because you don't get an answer, edit the question with more information to bump it to the top of the active page.

Answer (score 1):

For most Python packages, MacPorts has separate ports available for each supported Python version.  For example, if you are trying to use PIL (the Python Imaging Library), you need to install the 2.7 version of that port:

```
sudo port install py27-pil
```

That will also install the MacPorts version of Python 2.7, if you don't already have it installed.  It is located at `/opt/local/bin/python2.7`.