# Macports installs will not import

Tags: python, import, macports

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Locate MacPorts package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147035/locate-macports-package)
>   [Graphics folder modules will not import after several installs (Mac OSX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110885/graphics-folder-modules-will-not-import-after-several-installs-mac-osx)

I'm using python2.7, but also have 2.4 and the native MacOSX python installed.  After installing several modules using Macports, neither will import.

Here are the modules that will not import:

tiff @3.9.5 graphics/tiff

pngpp @0.2.3 graphics/pngpp

libgeotiff @1.3.0 graphics/libgeotiff

And this is an example error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named png
```

This is a reoccurring issue with my installed version of Macports.  What should I do to make sure whatever is installed by Macports will be imported by my currently used python?

Comment: Please stop asking duplicate questions. I'm merging this into your previous one.